# Cutting hole into a face with a line loop?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

How do I cut a hole in the plane using the hollow line loop in the middle they're part of the same mesh and both 2d.

[image]

Comment: Related, [Remove part of a plane](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/remove-part-of-a-plane).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert your objects to curves and select *2D* under the curve options. Doing this gives you a bit more flexibility as you can tweak the loop and see the changes as you do so. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> *> Curve from Mesh/Text* to do this.

[image]

Once you are finished tweaking, convert back to a mesh with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> *> Mesh from Curve/Meta/..*. You will notice that the plane is triangulated. To clean this up, run a *Limited Dissolve* on the mesh.

[image]

Done

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why we always need this two edges from outer border to inner one? Is it blender specific? And why two not one?

Comment: Thank you for `limited dissolve`. Thing is beautiful.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using [**Knife Project**](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Subdividing/Knife_Subdivide), however for the case you show to work, you will have to use a recent Blender build, since improved knife support was added after 2.69 release.

> To use Knife Project, in *Object* mode select the object you want to project (use and cut the other) first then <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the "object to be cut". Now <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit* mode and press *Knife project*.

[image] [image]

Before projecting from a text object and Resulting knife projection.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is the *Bridge* tool.

1. Delete the face of the plane (<kbd>Delete</kbd>*> Only Faces*)
2. Select all and press <kbd>W</kbd>*> Bridge Edge loops*:

   [image]

**Result:**

[image]

If you want to use ngons instead of tris, press <kbd>Delete</kbd>*> Limited Dissolve*:

[image]